# ios - waiting 24hrs to send a notification

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents

Our application sends a notification every morning at 8am to greet the user and remind him to complete a task. Here is the script we are using:

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["dailyReminder"])
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Good morning"
    content.body = notificationMessages[randomIndex]
    content.sound = .default
    
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 8

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "dailyReminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
```

This is called after the user finishes the day's task so that they are prompted the next day. However, some people finish the task before 8am. In those cases we'd like for the notification to be sent at 8am of the next day.

How could I calculate if the script runs before or after 8 and add 24 hrs accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is run locally you could just save the last time the function was sent by holding it in a UserDefault. For example, add the following to the code to save when the user has last done a task:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("/(youWillWriteAFunctionForDate)", forKey: "checkTaskOfDate")
```

Then you can simply check if it was sent today, and plan accordingly:

```
defaults.string(forKey: "checkTaskOfDate") ?? "Never Done"
```